# Баг flexbox и абсолютного позиционирования в Firefox

Tags: css, html5, css3, firefox, кроссбраузерность

Собственно, вот скриншот проблемы.
Сверху в низ: 1 - Chrome, 2 - Opera, 3 - Firefox, 4 - Edge.

[image: скриншот]

Ниже я привел запускаемый (надеюсь) код.
Для супер-максимального удобства, вот [codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/RKPrvE). На нем, мне кажется, удобнее.

Основная идея такая: надпись *Gallery* и логотип позиционировать в центр, а остальные - по бокам, но чтобы их размеры не учитывались для центрирования двух главных элементов надписи и логотипа.
`transform` будет использован для анимации, поэтому всё равно нужно позиционировать в центр и оттуда направлять остальные категории.

Безмерно буду благодарен, если поможете разобраться, как поддерживать flex в Firefox без обхода и переписывания всего кода позиционирования.

```css
.gallerypage {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.gallerypage .header {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}

.gallerypage .header a {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  text-indent: -6px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: "Kaushan Script", cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.gallerypage .header .sketches {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 110px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-400px, 0px);
      -ms-transform: translate(-400px, 0px);
          transform: translate(-400px, 0px);
}

.gallerypage .header .smth {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, 0px);
      -ms-transform: translate(-200px, 0px);
          transform: translate(-200px, 0px);
}

.gallerypage .header .gallery {
  position: static;
  text-indent: -14px;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 185px;
  height: 90px;
  background: gold;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.gallerypage .header .logo {
  position: static;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  background: hotpink;
}

.gallerypage .header .logo .vs-logo {
  display: block;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
}

.gallerypage .header .blog {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 60px;
  height: 38px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 0px);
      -ms-transform: translate(200px, 0px);
          transform: translate(200px, 0px);
}

.gallerypage .header .about {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(400px, 0px);
      -ms-transform: translate(400px, 0px);
          transform: translate(400px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallerypage">
  <div class="header">
    <a class="sketches">Sketches</a>
    <a class="smth">Something serious</a>
    <a class="gallery">Gallery</a><a class="logo"></a>
    <a class="blog">Blog</a><a class="about">About it</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Конкретнее говоря, это `position: absolute` и `display:flex` вместе как-то некорректно работают. Но это лишь моя догадка, я понятия не имею что к чему(

Comment: Очень прискорбно, что в случае чего проблема в браузере/библиотеке, а не вашем коде.

Comment: Зачем вы используете flexbox и абсолютное позиционирование? В данном случае абсолютное позиционирование — чистейший хак.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, а что мне использовать? Отрицательные маржины?

Comment: В принципе можно, но лучше без них. Там вся разметка прекрасно выполнима простым выравниванием по центру + немного `margin`.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, модернизировать на codepen можешь, пожалуйста? А то я не понимаю как центрировать по вертикали (допустим, маржинами выровнять по горизонтали), и чтобы остальные элементы обтекали лого и *Gallery*, но можно было задать фиксированное расстояние относительно самого центра header, а не привязываться к left (и так далее).

Comment: Я стандартов не читал, но по моей логике position:absolute внутри display:flex вполне тянет на неопределённое поведение, ибо хз как позиционировать-то с такими взаимоисключающими требованиями

Comment: @VostokSisters Можете отредактировать ваш вопрос и удалить оттуда эмоциональные жалобы? Они явно лишние. Вопрос очень неплох: про абсолютное позиционирование внутри flexbox. Но эти жалобы его портят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я удалил неуместные `position: absolute;` и `transform` на данном примере.

Вот решение чтобы элементы выглядели приблизительно как у вас на скриншоте, основанное на вашем коде.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script");

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: gray;
  padding: 5px;
}

.header a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: "Kaushan Script", cursive;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.header .sketches {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 110px;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.header .smth {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.header .gallery {
  width: 185px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: gold;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.header .logo {
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  background: hotpink;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.header .blog {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 60px;
  height: 38px;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.header .about {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a class="sketches">Sketches</a>
  <a class="smth">Something serious</a>
  <a class="gallery">Gallery</a>
  <a class="logo"></a>
  <a class="blog">Blog</a><a class="about">About it</a>
</div>
```

---

Для того, чтобы `.gallery` и `.logo` были чётко по центру обернём их отдельным `div` с классом `.center`. Остальные элементы (слева и справа) обернём в `div` с классом `.half`. Присвоим для `.half` `flex: 1;` чтобы элементы занимали оставшуюся ширину. Готовый пример:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script");

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  padding: 5px;
}

.half, .center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.half {
  flex: 1;
}

.header a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: "Kaushan Script", cursive;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.header .sketches {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 110px;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.header .smth {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.header .gallery {
  width: 185px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: gold;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.header .logo {
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  background: hotpink;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.header .blog {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 60px;
  height: 38px;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.header .about {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="half">
    <a class="sketches">Sketches</a>
    <a class="smth">Something serious</a>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <a class="gallery">Gallery</a>
    <a class="logo"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="half">
    <a class="blog">Blog</a>
    <a class="about">About it</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: это не совсем то... [Вот](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/06/0001/0403/94611/11/f77698cfb3.png) почему.

Comment: если бы всё было так просто))

Comment: Галерея и Лого должны быть прям по центру, слева и справа - одинаковые расстояния. Это ключевой момент, так что вопрос в использовании абсолютного позиционировании всё ещё открыт.  Я-то  знаю как центрировать элементы в контейнере, вопрос в другом же...

Comment: Я бы всё равно не стал прибегать к абсолютному позиционированию даже тут. Сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: Добавил изящное решение без хаков.

Comment: Я уже решил свою задачку) И даже без флекс-бокса. Но пришлось использовать хак для выравнивания абсолютно позиционированного элемента по центру контейнера, который заключается в том, что `left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0` присваиваются нули, а затем `margin: auto`.  А сами галлерея и лого выравниваются как inline-block элементы. Но я попозже добавлю это решение в ответ...

Comment: Написал ещё на англоязычный форум, там не дали решения, но зато объяснили, почему так происходит. И действительно, в Firefox есть такой баг, который заключается в том, что Firefox продолжает видеть и учитывать в flex-свойстве `align-items: center` элементы, даже если они заданы `position: absolute`. А Chrome и Opera абсол. позиционированные элементы игнорируют из расчета. Так-то. Вроде как дали ссылку на mozila dev., и вроде как там написано, что исправят в будущем.

Comment: [Вот](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/06/0001/0403/94611/11/c982533d97.png) как демонстрация успешного результата)

Comment: А зачем вам решение с абсолютным позиционированием? Я же вам предложил решение без хака.

Comment: А ещё эту задачу можно решить без flexbox. Через табличную вёрстку или `display: table;` и это всё равно будет лучше, чем хак с абсолютным позиционированием.

Comment: А дело в том, какая анимация будет применена к элементам, которые стоят по бокам лого и *Галереи*.  Они будут появляться из центра и расходиться по своим позициям, как на скришоте. Так что `transform: translate()` убирает двух зайцев сразу - можно сразу задать положение, а затем при ховере менять только `transition`. И для осуществления этого нужно, чтобы они были в центре `header`. Вот и получилась такая задачка)

Comment: А разве нельзя применить анимацию в моём случае?

Comment: Табличная верстка - это даже не хак, а убожество (мое огромное ИМХО). Не хочется это делать прям совсем). Но очень уж хочется услышать, почему лучше? Быстродействие? Или для понимания?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51333/discussion-between-vadim-ovchinnikov-and-vostoksisters).