# Абсолютное позиционирование элемента внутри флекс-контейнера, давайте разбираться

Tags: css, css3

Опять столкнулся с тем, что нужно использовать абсолютное позиционирование внутри флекс-контейнера, ничего с собой поделать не могу, нужно и всё тут.
Проблема, если коротко, такая:
[image: 123]
Собственно, такая проблема у меня уже [была](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611603/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B3-flexbox-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-firefox). Решения (конкретно ей) мне так и не дали, все лишь посоветовали сменить стиль позиционирования и в самом лучшем случае - отказаться от флекса, если всё-таки используешь его.
Ну я так и сделал. Но сейчас пришел к тому, что самым лучшим решением для верстки стало использование флекса, но и без аб. поз. не обойтись, а отложенная в долгий ящик проблема возникла опять.
Также, в прошлый раз, я вроде как узнал, что это баг ФФ, что о нем знают и собираются поправить. Но честно говоря, черт знает когда это произойдет...
Поэтому я снова пишу сюда, чтобы разобраться наконец, как обойти эту проблему, если **железно** нужно: использовать для контейнера свойство флекс и позиционировать вложенные элементы через флекс-свойства, которые также имеют абсолютное позиционирование.
Для удобства [codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/mRqQBg) и запускаемый код ниже.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body .flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
body .flex-container .flex-item {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: приведи пример разметки, где это надо обойти.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, у меня есть овелей на весь экран. Там есть картинка с рамкой, которая должна быть по центру всего экрана. А также там есть кнопка, которая включает блок снизу картинки, в котором приводится описание, так вот: ничего сдвигаться там не должно, при включении блока картинка должна оставаться по центру как и была, а блок с инфой должен дополняться снизу и создавать прокрутку. Можно было бы обойтись и без аб. поз, да? Но  ещё это всё я хочу анимировать, так что не обойтись без этого, мне кажется...

Comment: может быть вам поможет [calc](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp)

Comment: @Jenyokcoder, я знаю про calc, использую его. Но черт знает, видимо опять никто не сможет помочь и придется всё перепозиционировать снова...

Comment: если основной мотив использования флексбокса в оверлее — это вертикальное и горизонтальное выравнивание, то можно обойтись и без флексбокса и выровнять методом абс. поз.